# Python: wrong ip is shown in packet header

Tags: python, sockets, networking, ip, packet

I'm forwarding a machine's packets through mine. I tested with `tcpdump host <machine_ip>` to see if everything is alright, and it is. Now I need to capture these packets. I chose to do this with Python. Right now I'm trying to filter the packets, but the ip that is printed is different from the right one. It should've been `192.168.0.8`:

```
import socket
from struct import *
print("Started")
with socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET,socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(0x0003)) as s:
        while True:
                packet=s.recvfrom(65565)
                content=packet[0]
                ip_header=unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s', content[:20])
                source_ip=socket.inet_ntoa(ip_header[8])
                print(source_ip)
```

The printed ones are `8.0.69.0` and `8.0.69.16`, which none of these matches the expected form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in front of the raw data is the MAC header.

If You change the line:

`ip_header=unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s', content[:20])`

to

`ip_header=unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s', content[14:34])`

You will probably get your ip address. I said probably becase it really depends on the link layer, as there might be a vlan tag present, thus shifting the ip header even further.

Comment: Thx, I managed to get it to work with information u provided.